# How to get all characters from the right up to the particular character in dart

Tags: string, flutter, dart, substring

I am trying to get all characters from the right up to the '*' from below string.

String phoneNumber = '07*** ***253'

Here I want the substring as '253'

ex:  '07*** ***4253'
result: 4253

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the string with split()

```
var _phone = "07*** ***253";

String _last =  _phone.split('*').last;
```

Or same with regexp

```
   RegExp reg = RegExp(r'[^*]*$');
    var _matched = reg.allMatches(_phone);

    _matches.last.group(0);
```